# make delay after each() function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to animate each `.dot` after a 3 seconds delay after previous `.dot`
Here is the code I used. But it doesn't work.

```
var time = 3000;

$(".dot").each(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).addClass("animate");
    $(this).find(".num").addClass("animate");
  }, time)
  time += 3000;
});
```

Comment: For consistency sake add your markup (HTML, CSS) as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` doesn't refers to element in [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), hence its not working.

You can pass parameters to the function

```
var time = 3000;
$(".dot").each(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function (self) {
        self.addClass("animate");
        self.find(".num").addClass("animate");
    }, (i + 1) * time, $(this));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(".dot").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(3000 * i).addClass("animate");
  $(this).find(".num").delay(3000 * i).addClass("animate");  
});
```